# Use zsh instead of bash in Sagemaker Studio

Tags: dockerfile, zsh, amazon-sagemaker

I have created an image that uses `zsh` as entrypoint and attached it to my Sagemaker Studio domain (I can use `zsh` just fine if I test the image locally using `docker run`), but when opening a terminal in the Studio with this custom image, I see it falls back to `bash`.

Is there a way to actually have the Studio terminal use the image I've provided?